# Error when copying files: "ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket, copyfile"

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, fs, file-copying

I'm trying to copy files between folders in a mounted directory.

I create a new dir (and set chmod 777) and then copy like so:

```
async ({ destDir, files }) => {
    return await Promise.all(
      files.map((filePath) => {
        const fileName = path.basename(filePath);

        return fs
          .copyFile(filePath, path.join(destDir, fileName))
          .then(() => fs.chmod(filePath, "777"));
      }),
    );
  }
```

and getting this error which I can find nothing about:

```
ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket, copyfile ....
```

Any solution would be welcome

Comment: I solved this by using a library for copying that uses a stream (`cp-file`). Still not sure why `fs.copyFile` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Node 14 and copying files between NFS mounts: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/36439

It *should* be resolved [as of Node.js 14.18.2](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/36439#issuecomment-1003571800), so either update to a newer version of Node or (if you're stuck) try an alternative copying mechanism (see [this example](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/36439#issuecomment-765403311)).